# ES 1.7.5 How to mimic match_none behavior?

Tags: elasticsearch

Match_none was introduced in later versions, but there has to be a way to mimic the behavior in 1.7.5? Any leads would be appreciated.

Basically, I want to return a query which will match no documents, but my global aggregations would still run.

Answer (score 0):

Found out I can use MustNot in combination with MatchAll (must not match all)